# JSON Schema (v04) anyOf with dependencies

Tags: jsonschema

I have a JSON that can have either an `IBAN` account number, in which case a `BIC` is required, or an `account_number` or both of them.

So, this is valid (only `account_number`):

```
"bankaccount_data": [
    {
        "bic": null,
        "iban": null,
        "account_name": "Bankgiro",
        "account_number": "12345-6789",
        "bank_name": "Bankgiro",
        "type": "Bankgiro"
    }
]
```

And this is valid with `iban` and `bic`:

```
"bankaccount_data": [
    {
        "bic": "BANKBIC",
        "iban": "SE0123456789",
        "account_name": "Bankgiro",
        "account_number": null,
        "bank_name": "Bankgiro",
        "type": "Bankgiro"
    }
]
```

Even this with both `account_number` and `iban/bic`:

```
"bankaccount_data": [
    {
        "bic": "BANKBIC",
        "iban": "SE0123456789",
        "account_name": "Bankgiro",
        "account_number": "12345-6789",
        "bank_name": "Bankgiro",
        "type": "Bankgiro"
    }
]
```

My problem is with requiring BOTH `iban` and `bic` if either/or exists. I have this schema which is not doing that but should "illustrate" my need:

```
"bankaccount_data": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "account_name": { "type": "string" },
        "bank_name": { "type": [ "string", "null" ] },
        "type": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": [ "type" ],
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "bic":   { "type": "string" },
            "iban": { "type": "string" }
          },
          "required": [ "bic", "iban" ],
          "dependencies": {
              "iban": [
                  "bic"
              ],
              "bic": [
                "iban"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "account_number":   { "type": "string" }
          },
          "required": [ "account_number" ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To avoid potential errors, please include a fully working Schema. You can use https://jsonschema.dev to easily share also.

Comment: Although... not with draft-04. Stil, please provide a full schema.

Comment: Actually, got it... hold on =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't quite sure, but I think you're asking for, if `iban` or `bic` is present, then the other must also be present.

You had the right ideas here. However it's complicated by the fact that your values can be null as opposed to simply not present.

`dependencies` only checks the properties are present, not anything to do with their value. `null` is still a value. `dependencies` cannot help you in your situation, as you always expect the keys to be present in the object.

First let's look at the solution.

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "bic":   { "type": "string" },
        "iban": { "type": "string" },
        "account_number": { "enum": [null]}
      },
      "required": [
        "iban",
        "bic"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "account_number"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "bic":   { "enum": [null] },
        "iban": { "enum": [null] },
        "account_number": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://jsonschema.dev/s/dg0CY

The reason you need this sort of duplication, is you need to fully express the condition that your checking.

The values of an `anyOf` array are subschemas. The values are full schemas on their own.

Taking your values for `anyOf`, `anyOf[0]` does express the constraint that your looking for, however `anyOf[1]` says nothing about `iban` or `bic`, and so "any of" the schemas is considered valid. Each value in `anyOf` is not aware of the contense of the other; only the results are combined.

JSON Schema is constraints based, so anything NOT expressed, is allowed.

In the solution I've provided above, each schema in `anyOf` checks fully for the required condition.

For your example, it works in draft-07 the same as draft-04, so the demo is the same.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks!
I needed to add a third option in "anyOf" with `required` on all three as you should be able to have "bic", "iban" AND "account_number" as well.

Comment: And https://jsonschema.dev/ is just awsome so Thanks for that one as well! :)

Comment: If you can make them not defined as opposed to defined with a value of null, it's a LOT simpler =] I didn't notice the nulls first time round.

Comment: And you're welcome. If you're able to and so inclined, feel free to support the service / buy me a coffee =]

Comment: Very much appreciated! Should you have questions that don't fit on Stack Overflow, feel free to come by our (JSON Schema) very active slack server